# Error on import FacebookSDK

Tags: facebook-android-sdk, android-support-library

I downloaded Facebook API 3.0 and I imported it to Eclipse (Helion). I created new project of my app (called HAN Communication) and I tried to add as library FacebookSDK. But after this I seen this error(s) :

```
[2013-02-03 11:28:06 - HANCommunication] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-02-03 11:28:06 - HANCommunication] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-02-03 11:28:06 - HANCommunication] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-02-03 11:28:06 - HANCommunication] Versions found are:
[2013-02-03 11:28:06 - HANCommunication] Path: D:\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-02-03 11:28:06 - HANCommunication]    Length: 349252
[2013-02-03 11:28:06 - HANCommunication]    SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
[2013-02-03 11:28:06 - HANCommunication] Path: D:\workspace\space\HANCommunication\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-02-03 11:28:06 - HANCommunication]    Length: 385685
[2013-02-03 11:28:06 - HANCommunication]    SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
[2013-02-03 11:28:06 - HANCommunication] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2013-02-03 11:29:17 - HANCommunication] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-02-03 11:29:17 - HANCommunication] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-02-03 11:29:17 - HANCommunication] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-02-03 11:29:17 - HANCommunication] Versions found are:
[2013-02-03 11:29:17 - HANCommunication] Path: D:\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-02-03 11:29:17 - HANCommunication]    Length: 349252
[2013-02-03 11:29:17 - HANCommunication]    SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
[2013-02-03 11:29:17 - HANCommunication] Path: D:\workspace\space\HANCommunication\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-02-03 11:29:17 - HANCommunication]    Length: 385685
[2013-02-03 11:29:17 - HANCommunication]    SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
[2013-02-03 11:29:17 - HANCommunication] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2013-02-03 11:34:45 - HANCommunication] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-02-03 11:34:45 - HANCommunication] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-02-03 11:34:45 - HANCommunication] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-02-03 11:34:45 - HANCommunication] Versions found are:
[2013-02-03 11:34:45 - HANCommunication] Path: D:\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-02-03 11:34:45 - HANCommunication]    Length: 349252
[2013-02-03 11:34:45 - HANCommunication]    SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
[2013-02-03 11:34:45 - HANCommunication] Path: D:\workspace\space\HANCommunication\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-02-03 11:34:45 - HANCommunication]    Length: 385685
[2013-02-03 11:34:45 - HANCommunication]    SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
[2013-02-03 11:34:45 - HANCommunication] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

My manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.radzik.hancommunication"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.radzik.hancommunication.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried to change target API version, but this isn't helpful for me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the libs directory in your app project folder. If there is a android-support-v4.jar in there, this is the cause of the error. Facebook SDK has included a version of this jar already and apparently they don't match. I solved this problem by removing the jar from my app project.

I suspect the cause of the mismatch is that the android SDK jar has been updated since the one the SDK was developed with.